# registering a const type reference object as C++ class member object

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference

I am trying to pass a `const` reference object of `class B` to an object of `class A`. So that class A member function foo() can access member function `bar()` of `class B`. This below method works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B {
public:
    void bar() const { cout << "Bar"; }
};

class A {
public:
    A (const B& _b) : b(_b) {}
    void foo () { cout << "Foo"; b.bar(); }
private:
    const B& b;
};

main()
{
     B b1;
     A a1(b1);
     a1.foo();
}
```

However, instead of passing the `b1` object in constructor of A, i am looking for a way to register the object `b1` at a later stage. The way mentioned below has errors, but is there any way to achieve this ?

```
class A {
public:
    A () {};
    void registerB(const B& _b) { b =_b; }      // Assignement not possible
    void foo () { cout << "Foo ";  b.bar(); }
private:
    const B& b;
};

main()
{
     B b1;
     A a1;
     // Do some work
     a1.registerB(b1);
     a1.foo();
}
```

**EDIT**

If the B object is not `const`, can it be made to work then ?

```
class A {
public:
    A ():b(NULL) {};
    void registerB(B& _b) { b =_b; }      // Assignement not possible
    void foo () { cout << "Foo ";  b.bar(); }
private:
    B& b;     // Not const
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can const members be modified in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525941/why-can-const-members-be-modified-in-a-constructor)

Comment: `void registerB(B& _b) { b =_b; }` *copies* `_b`. `A (const B& _b) : b(_b) {}` *references* `_b`. By design you can't change what object a reference points to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference must refer to a variable. Unlike a pointer, it can not have a value indicating emptiness (like `nullptr`).

As such, class A cannot have a reference that is not assigned in the constructor. What would `a1.b` be equal to before you called `a1.registerB(b1)`?

The only way to do this, would be for class A to have a pointer to a class B. That way it could be null when `A` is constructed.

i.e.

```
class A {
    public:
       A():pb(nullptr) {};
       void registerB(const B *_pB) { pB = _pB; }
    private:
       const B *pB;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i understand. But can it be done with reference but without const ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Where do you not want the const? You can't have A store a reference to B without initializing it in the constructor, you can only store a pointer.
You can have your function registerB take a ref though and then capture the address of it, but it's not a great idea since the caller doesn't know that it's passing it's address to someone else. ie void registerB(B &b) { pB = &b; }

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly this is what i wanted. Storing the reference in a pointer made sense, the registerB function can sill be have reference type as argument.

Comment: kernelman - I would stay away taking a reference and then storing a pointer unless you absolutely have to. It's much clearer to have void registerB(B *_pB) { pB = _pB; } and then call it like a.registerB(&b); Then at least caller knows that their address might be captured.

At the end of the day, who owns the "B"? By capturing the address, you have to be careful that B does not go out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a temporary object for a reference.

```
class A {
public:
    A() : b{} {} // create temporary
    void registerB(B& _b) { b = _b; }  // Assign later
    void foo () { std::cout << "Foo ";  b.bar(); }
private:
    B&& b;
};
```

NOTE: this will have a warning:

> a temporary bound to 'A::b' only persists until the constructor exits
>   [-Wextra]

Thus, this will cause undefined behavior if you forgot to call `registerB()`.

See more [Prolong life of a temporary object using const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763741/prolonging-life-of-a-temporary-object-using-const-reference)

Comment: this method is already mentioned in the question. I wanted a way to register B later.