# Differenciate const int *ptr; int const *ptr;

Tags: c++, oop, c++17

Differentiate between: (elaborate with diagrams)
a. const int *ptr;
b. int const *ptr;

Can anyone explain the concept- I understand a little bit about first but not about second - If they are same then why C++ gives us two different syntax to use it.

Comment: Nothing in that code is an "attribute" as far as C++ is concerned. There's a data member, a non-static one. But that's not an attribute".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize a const field in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423696/how-to-initialize-a-const-field-in-constructor)

Comment: FYI: [SO: **Why can const members be modified in a constructor?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49525941/7478597)

Answer (score 1):

Why not? You can write

```
class A {
  const int i = 0;
};
```

or

```
class A {
const int i = 0;
public:
  A() {}
  A(int j) : i(j) {}
};
```

Comment: Can we change the value of const int i = 0; in the first one. Because changing value is big problem. If we can change the value in first one then its okay? can you tell me?

Comment: You can change `const int i = 0;` like `A(int j) : i(j) {}`. If you call `A a;` you get `i==0`, but `A a(10)` you get `i==10`